# Impossibly difficult to track down original rom I8262BUUBAMG1

Tags: samsung, device-firmware, stock-android

I have had no luck in trying to find a site that hosts the ROM for my galaxy core. Is there someplace that I am missing?

I8262BUUBAMG1

I love the modded rom  that [Omkar$](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2520999) mas made but the latest update broke the google play store connection and I am not having any luck trying to get it to work.

If someone has some insight on how to attempt a fix without installing stock firmware that would be awesome. But if not stock will have to do until he fixes the problem with the gAPPs.

Thanks ahead of time guys!

EDIT:

I did find the ROM [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/?model=GT-I8262B&pcode=0#firmware) but links are broken -.- fml

Comment: Have you checked with [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: Yeah I checked out a lot of different places to find that specific rom and it has been very difficult. I have been modding my phones for a while and I always have a go to. But for some odd reason this galaxy core GT-I8262B has been a real pain. I don't know if there would be a problem flashing the stock GT-IS8262 rom on it for india. I just don't want to keep running odin over and over again.

Comment: I see. Sorry, but I don't know a specific location for that. With some luck, someone having that device might help further.

Comment: No worries!! Thanks for the link btw there are A LOT of sites I hadn't tried yet!

Comment: That's why I suggested it :) It's our biggest resource on this topic. If you know some sources missing there, be welcome to add!